# The package libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, dependencies, steam

today on logging in to my laptop (Lenovo Thinkpad T460s),I noticed a little red kind of "⛔️" icon in the top bar of my screen, I am using Ubuntu 20.04 64-bit by the way, anyway when I clicked into it, it told me that I had a certain package called libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 that needed to be reinstalled but there is no archive for it, and that it usually means that my installed packages have unmet dependencies. Now from doing further research I found out this package is related to Steam Installer and when I found out I attempted to remove Steam Installer, but then at the top it said, "Unable to remove "Steam Installer": Removing not available." For further information on what the "error" message looked like, I have attached an image below.
[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0A67.png)

I have ran `apt-cache policy libgl1-mesa-dri:i386` and the output

```
libgl1-mesa-dri:
  Installed: 20.2.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1
  Candidate: 20.2.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1
  Version table:
 *** 20.2.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     20.0.4-2ubuntu1 500
        500 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
libgl1-mesa-dri:i386:
  Installed: 20.2.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1
  Candidate: 20.2.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1
  Version table:
 *** 20.2.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     20.0.4-2ubuntu1 500
        500 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
```

Comment: Please add output of `apt-cache policy libgl1-mesa-dri libgl1-mesa-dri:i386` to the question.

Comment: @N0rbert I have added the output, is the way i added the output correct? If so please tell me and I will rewrite it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You miss the *focal-updates* and/or *focal-security* repository pockets.

Open Software & Updates (`software-properties-gtk`) and enable these components back by visiting *Updates* tab and setting *For other packages, subscribe to* to *All Updates*.

Then updates using

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get instal -f
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: I thank you very much for all this, the error message has disappeared.